# Worklight how to make native alert box without title

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Using worklight WL.SimpleDialog.show

```
 WL.SimpleDialog.show("", "body",
                    [
                        {text:"OK"}
                    ]);
```

It display an alert box but with extra blank space in the area where should be the title.

How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

When using WL.SimpleDialog, it is expected that you'll have a title. Not adding title text does not mean the title area is removed completely.

If you want your own custom title, you can create it on your own using the various options available online. For example, Vex: http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/

Comment: i am looking for any solution that is ready of us from worklight. maybe i will just use alert